# resolve [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized] with function pointer that is only initialized during runtime

Tags: c, oop, pointers

I am writing a piece of code in C11 that is supposed to make my life easier later on in the program. I have a general `intersect` function I want to call. Depending on some circumstances however, that `intersect` function may actually be a different function.

Note that the pointer type of the third argument of `intersect` depends on a switch case, so I can't really generalize it.

The same error also appears for `getnormal`.

The error:

```
error: ‘intersect’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
   57 |   current_t = intersect(origin, direction, objects[i]);
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

The code:

```
float inline iPlane(vec3 origin, vec3 direction, plane * pla);
float inline iTriangle(vec3 origin, vec3 direction, triangle * tri);
float inline iSphere(vec3 origin, vec3 direction, sphere * sph);

vec3 inline nTriangle(triangle * obj, vec3 position);
vec3 inline nPlane(plane * obj, vec3 position);
vec3 inline nSphere(sphere * obj, vec3 position);


    float current_t;

    vec3 (*getnormal)();
    float (*intersect)();

    object * nearest_obj = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < object_count; ++i)
    {
        switch(objects[i]->shape){ // shape = enum{sphereobj, triangleobj, planeobj}
            case triangleobj:
                getnormal = &nTriangle; // real function that exists
                intersect = &iTriangle; // also a real function that exists
                break;
            case sphereobj:
                getnormal = &nSphere;
                intersect = &iSphere;
                break;
            case planeobj:
                getnormal = &nPlane;
                intersect = &iPlane;
                break;
        }

        current_t = intersect(origin, direction, objects[i]); // error here
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get rid of the warning, just initialize your function pointer variable to 0.

```
float (*intersect)() = NULL;
```

then before using it, check that it's been initialized (just in case all enumerates aren't covered in the `switch` statement, in which case another warning would be raised, but better safe than sorry)

```
assert (intersect);
```

or without assert (which can be eliminated with some compiler switches)

```
if (!intersect)
{
  // handle the error
}
```

If the case *can* happen:

```
if (intersect)
{
   current_t = intersect(origin, direction, objects[i]);
}
else
{
   current_t = 0.0; // some default value else you get the "uninitialized error" with current_t
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler has no way to guarantee that `objects[i]->shape` is just a value from the enumeration. From the compiler's point of view `objects[i]->shape` is just an `int` value.

The quick solution is to add a `default` case which uses some sensible default values.

Another solution is to initialize the pointers to `NULL`, and then have a check for that before using them.

Comment: Something I find irritating in C (or is it gcc?) is that if the shape field was an enum (eg there was an explicit enum in the definition of the structure) so that the compiler has been told shape will be one of the given values, you still need to put in a default to avoid a warning.

Comment: @dmuir It's because in C enumeration values are just a nice way to do consecutive integer symbolic constants. There's nothing in the C specification to stop one from doing e.g. `objects[i]->shape = 1234`. C++ solved it with scoped enumerations, but their plain non-scoped enumerations still is very much close to the C semantics.